# How do I add a Sprite to the stage in runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, jquery-animate, sprite

I'm trying to get the hang of using AS3 to add objects to the stage.  I understand that with the new Adobe Animate, using Sprites can be more efficient than always using MCs, so I'm trying to figure out how that's done and I keep finding mostly old tutorials involving only MCs and not Sprites, per se.  So, ANY helpful information using Sprites is appreciated.

Now, my *specific* problem is this:

```
package 
{ 
    import flash.display.Sprite

    public class Ship extends Sprite
    { 
        public function addShip():void
        {
            trace("addShip function run");
        } 
    } 
}
```

which is all in a file called Ship.as which I have linked to my file Ship.fla in the Actionscript Settings menu under the File menu.
Then, in my Ship.fla file, the first frame of the main timeline has:

```
ShipMc:Ship = new Ship();
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addShip);
```

which gives these errors:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Ship to an unrelated type Class.
1188: Illegal assignment to class Ship.
1120: Access of undefined property addShip.
```

Comment: Unset your document class (or use another class), and then in your main timeline (or your document class, ...) for example you can do : `var ShipMc:Ship = new Ship(); addChild(ShipMc);`, this will work but you'll see nothing in the stage as your Sprite is empty, you have to draw/add something in it to see it of course. Take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) for more about Sprite ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [method (function) in subClass not being called on mouse event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580393/method-function-in-subclass-not-being-called-on-mouse-event)

Answer (score 1):

Missing var maybe? Correct code should be:

```
stop();//if you are adding things on timeline, and in case you have more then 1 frame

    var ShipMc:Ship = new Ship();
    addChild(ShipMc);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ShipMc.addShip); //this makes the whole stage clickable
   //ShipMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addShip) - in case you want only the ship to be clickable
```